# Can't start Android Virtual Device

Tags: android, macos, android-virtual-device

Im trying to emulate my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 with Android Studio 0.8.9 on Mac OS X 10.6.8.
But when I start the AVD I always got this error message:

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'SamsungGalaxyTab2_10.1'
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _memmem
  Referenced from: /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/tools/emulator64-arm
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
dyld: Symbol not found: _memmem
  Referenced from: /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/tools/emulator64-arm
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

I tried different configurations. This is my current one:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hk7Qz.png

Answer (score 0):

This is an unfortunate error! The latest minimum supported version for Android Studio is now 10.8, so you may need to download an older version to use, update your OS, or try using Eclipse instead. You can find details and a link to older versions here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77397